# Is it possible to use Canvas or KineticJS to create Mesh Density Animation?

Tags: animation, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have been asked to create animation like this 
http://vimeo.com/42731134 
by using HTML5 Canvas or , KineticJS(Filters with image).

I did the search with keywords like, "canvas mesh animation", "KineticJS mesh animation" but did not come out anything useful.

if Canvas can not do this, are there any development languages can do it?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can do this using canvas - canvas is just a bitmap, but you'll have to provide the mesh code yourself using JavaScript (as with any language).

Comment: thanks. but what do you mean by "provide the mesh code yourself"?. do you mean, for example, if the animations have 4 scenes, than 4 mesh code need to be generated. are there any tools can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really an animation (as this term is used for canvas) because it just shows different bitmaps created with a program. The animation here is just to show all these pictures in a time frame.

To produce these pictures you have to provide this external program and call it yourself (eventually in the animation callback loop, demo: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-animation-tutorial/ ).

I don't know if you can use gimp or some other program to create the images, I never did that myself.
Also, I don't know about a javascript library which can do that.

If you have a fixed animation sequence in mind (like in the video link you provided) you could just make a video or an animated gif instead and forget all the canvas voodoo.